# Hartogs Theorem and Canonical Bundles

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, dg.differential-geometry, complex-geometry

Let $X$ be a normal complex affine algebraic variety. Suppose that $Y$ is an open subvariety of $X$, and that the codimension of $X\setminus Y$ in $X$ is at least $2$. One version of the Hartogs Theorem is that the restriction map $\mathbb{C}[X]\rightarrow\mathbb{C}[Y]$ is surjective. I am curious about whether there is a version of the Hartogs Theorem for extending sections of canonical bundles. Specifically, if $\alpha$ is a global section of the canonical bundle on $Y$, does there exist a global section $\beta$ of the canonical bundle on $X$ such that $\beta\vert_Y=\alpha$? I would appreciate any and all references and suggestions.

Comment: What is an example of an open subvariety Y of X whose codimension is at least 2?


Comment: oops sorry i misread.

Comment: Hartogs' theorem is always misattributed: the one in the OP is Riemann's extension theorem (extension through analytic subsets of codimension $\geq 2$). Hartogs' is about extending through *compact* subsets.

Comment: (continued) See: Fritzsche, Grauert, *From holomorphic functions to complex manifolds*, Theorem 6.12.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think the property you want is that the canonical sheaf $\omega_X$ is S2.  Note that on a normal affine variety, $\omega_X$ is *not* necessarily a line bundle (it is if $X$ is a complete intersection though).

For simplicity, let's assume $X \subseteq A^{n}$ is of dimension $d$.  Then 
$$
\omega_X = Ext^{n-d}(O_X, O_{A^{n}})
$$
is a S2 sheaf.  This implies that it satisfies Hartog's theorem.  Not all sheaves do!  For example, the ideal sheaf of a maximal ideal obviously does not (assuming $\dim X \geq 2$).

For a reference which discusses the S2 condition and relation to Hartog's phenomenon, see for example

Hartshorne, *Generalized divisors on Gorenstein schemes*.

I think Sándor Kovács has also written several good answers explaining this connection on mathoverflow.

A proof of the S2ness of $\omega_X$ for varieties can be found in Kollár-Mori, *Birational geometry of algebraic varieties*.  Another proof can be found in Hartshorne's *Generalized divisors and biliaison*.

Comment: It's also relevant that $\omega_X |_Y = \omega_Y$, which follows from the definitions and is more or less (?) equivalent to the statement that open embeddings are smooth morphisms.

Comment: I really appreciate this answer! I am curious, however, about whether the cotangent sheaves of $X$ and $Y$ might also satisfy this Hartogs extension property. Do you happen to know if this is the case?

Comment: @Charles sure, it's definitely implied by that.  I think it's more basic though to see that dualizing complexes/sheaves commute with localization (at least depending on your definition).

Comment: @PDC  I don't think that's true in general (let me know if you need an example, I can probably cook one up).  Sometimes people take the reflexification/S2-ification of these sheaves though, and then study those properties.

You might see the paper of Manuel Blickle *Cartier isomorphism for toric varieties* or the paper of Greb, Kebekus, Kovács *Extension theorems for differential forms and Bogomolov-Sommese vanishing on log canonical varieties.* (and the followup with the additional author Peternell *Differential Forms on Log Canonical Spaces.*) 

Comment: @Karl Schwede, might you be able to direct me to a statement that $\omega_X$ satisfies $S_2$ for $X$ normal affine? I think that  Kollár-Mori proves this for $X$ projective, and I have been unable to find the result in Hartshorne's work. I really appreciate this!

Comment: @PDC Ah, but any affine variety already can be embedded in a projective variety.  Additionally $S2$ is a local condition.  This should let you reduce the affine case to the projective case.   The reference in the paper of Hartshorne is Lemma 1.3, note $S1$ is always satisfied on any integral scheme.  